# Create superuser using python manage.py customize the message in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

In a project requires the user name is autogenerated code. For that, I made a custom user model as described requirements. All is working fine but the problem is when I am trying to create superuser using

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

As I described the username is an auto-generated field. But the console asking me for the user name.
After creating a superuser account the user code will need to print out as I need code for login along with superuser is created successfully.

How can I gain this functionality? I search on google but I can't find any suitable solution.

Here is my model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""Custom user model"""
code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
nid = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'), ('Other', 'Other')])

is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = 'code'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

Here is my Custom User manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
use_in_migrations = True

def create_user(self, password, **extra_fields):
    """Create new user with auto-generated code and password"""
    if 'name' not in extra_fields.keys():
        raise ValueError('Name must be needed')
    code = code_generator.generate_employee_code(extra_fields['name'][:2])
    user = self.model(code=code, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    if 'email' in extra_fields.keys():
        email = self.normalize_email(extra_fields['email'])
        user.email = email
    try:
        user.save(using=self._db)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        raise ValueError("Email has already been used")
    return user

def create_superuser(self, name, password):
    """Create and save super user"""
    user = self.create_user(password=password, name=name)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by changing the source code, but generally not a good idea.

If you still want to try it out, here you go.

Find this file createsuperuser.py (site-packages->django->contrib->auth->management>commands) and add the code in the right place.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    ...
    ...
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
    ...
    ...
        if username:
            ...
            if options['verbosity'] >= 1:
                ...
                self.stdout.write("User name:" + username) # add this code
```

Again, am not saying that this a good idea, but if am desperate, I would go for this. Also since site-packages is not part of the repository, you will have to do this on each machine you deploy the application.

Comment: You can also write your own command for manage.py. <app-name>/management/commands/my-command.py. Then you'd run it with python manage.py my-command.